# C# expression, equivalent to ruby's sandwich block code

Tags: c#, ruby, block

I am a .NET developer and recently started learning ruby with ruby_koans. Some of Ruby's syntaxes are amazing and one of them is the way it handles "Sandwich" code.

The following is ruby sandwich code.

```
  def file_sandwich(file_name)
    file = open(file_name)
    yield(file)
  ensure
    file.close if file
  end

  def count_lines2(file_name)
    file_sandwich(file_name) do |file|
      count = 0
      while line = file.gets
        count += 1
      end
      count
    end
  end

  def test_counting_lines2
    assert_equal 4, count_lines2("example_file.txt")
  end
```

I am fascinated that I can get rid of the cumbersome "file open and close code" each time I access a file but cannot think of any C# equivalent code. Maybe, I can use IoC's dynamic proxy to do the same thing, but is there any way I can do it purely with C#?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You certainly don't need anything IoC-related here. How about:

```
public T ActOnFile<T>(string filename, Func<Stream, T> func)
{
    using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(stream))
    {
        return func(stream);
    }
}

public int CountLines(string filename)
{
    return ActOnFile(filename, stream =>
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            int count = 0;
            while (reader.ReadLine() != null)
            {
                count++;
            }
            return count;
        }
    });
}
```

In this case it doesn't help very much, as the `using` statement already does most of what you want... but the general principle holds. Indeed, that's how LINQ is so flexible. If you haven't looked at LINQ yet, I strongly recommend that you do.

Here's the *act* `CountLines` method I'd use:

```
public int CountLines(string filename)
{
    return File.ReadLines(filename).Count();
}
```

Note that this will still only read a line at a time... but the `Count` extension method acts on the returned sequence.

In .NET 3.5 it would be:

```
public int CountLines(string filename)
{
    using (var reader = File.OpenText(filename))
    {
        int count = 0;
        while (reader.ReadLine() != null)
        {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

... still pretty simple.

Comment: Many thanks. I was looking for a C# way to handle sandwich code and this is it.

Answer (score 3):

are you just looking for something that opens and closes the stream for you?

```
public IEnumerable<string>GetFileLines(string path)
{
    //the using() statement will open, close, and dispose your stream for you:
    using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
    {
       //do stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `yield return` what you're looking for?

`using` will call Dispose() and Close() when it reaches the closing brace, but I think the question is how to achieve this particular structure of code.

Edit: Just realized that this isn't exactly what you're looking for, but I'll leave this answer here since a lot of people aren't aware of this technique.

```
static IEnumerable<string> GetLines(string filename)
{
    using (var r = new StreamReader(filename))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
            yield return line;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetLines("file.txt").Count());

    //Or, similarly: 

    int count = 0;
    foreach (var l in GetLines("file.txt"))
        count++;
    Console.WriteLine(count);
}
```